# What are the works of Tulsidas Ji?

Tags: krishna, rama, sita, tulsidas, ramanand

What are the works of Tulsidas Ji? Please give details of their timings?

Answer (score 1):

सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।

Śrīmad Goswami Tulsidas Ji Maharāj was Incarnation of Śrīmad Mahārishi Vālmiki (about which we will talk at the end). He wrote many compositions and short compositions to give the nectar of eternal bliss of pastimes of Paratpār Par-Brahmā Śrī SītāRām;

Works of Śrīmad Tulsidās Ji~

1. Vairaagya Sandipani-it was written roughly between Samvat 1626 and 1627 (A.D. 1569-70).
2. Ram-agya-prashna-it was written roughly between Samvat 1627 and 1628 (A.D. 1570-71).
3. Ram-lalaa Nahachhu-it was written roughly between Samvat 1628 and 1629 (A.D. 1571-72).
4. Janki Mangal-it was written roughly between Samvat 1629 and 1630 (A.D. 1572- 73).
5. Ram Charit Manas-the writing of this great epic was started in Samvat 1631 (A.D. 1574).
6. Parvati Mangal-again, it was started in Samvat 1643 (A.D. 1586)---the date of conclusion is not determined.
7. Geetawali (Ram Geetawali)-it was written roughly between Samvat 1630 and 1670 (A.D. 1573-1613).
8. Vinay Patrika-it was written roughly between Samvat 1631 and 1679 (A.D. 1574–1622).
9. Dohawali-it was written roughly between Samvat 1626 and 1680 (A.D. 1569–1623).
10. Barvai Ramayan-it was written roughly between Samvat 1630 and 1680 (A.D.1573-1623).
11. Kavitawali-it was written roughly between Samvat 1631 and 1680 (A.D. 1574–1623)
12. Hanuman Baahuk-it was written roughly between Samvat 1631 and 1680 (A.D.1574-1623).
13. Krishna Geetawali- it was written roughly between Samvat 1643 and 1660 (A.D. 1586-1603).
14. Tulsi Satsai- it is written roughly between Samvat 1644 and 1660 (A.D. 1587–1603).

Here completed all his elaborated works.

Now his short compositions are~

1. Hanuman Chalisa-This work is a prayer to lord hanuman consisting 40 Chaupies and two Dohas.
2. Hanumanastak / Sankat Mochan- This is a devotional hymn (strotra) detailing notable exploits of the Śrī Hanuman Ji.

Now coming to who was Śrīmad Tuslidās?

Śrīmad Göswāmi Tulsidās was Incarnation of Śrīmad Mahārishi Vālmiki who incarnated in this Kali-Yuga to give the nectar of eternal bliss of Paratpār Par-Brahmā Śrī SītāRām,

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
रामचन्द्रकथामेतां भाषाबद्धां करिष्यति ॥

(Bhavishya Purān Pratisarg 4.20)

Lord Shankara says to Goddess Parvati – “O Parvati! Maharishi Valmiki will become Tulsidas in Kali Yuga and will translate this Rama Katha into vernacular (Awadhi) language.”

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वी भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥

(Shīv Samhitā~Excerpted from Gita Press Gorakhpur Veda Katha Ank, Page No. 285)

Lord Shiva siad to Maa Pārvati-”O Devi, Valmiki will incarnate as Tulsidās in the age of Kali to translate (complex) story of Śrī Rām Chandra in to simple language.

Sri Vaishnava Acharya Srimad Goswami Nabhadas Ji Maharaj, the author of Bhaktamal, also wrote the same about Tulsidas in his book Bhaktmāl (1585)

"कलि कुटिल जीव निस्तार हित वाल्मीक तुलसी भयो"

(Bhaktamal, 129 Chhappai, Page. 131, Maluk Peeth edition)

Valmiki took incarnation as Tulsidas to cross the ocean of death for the creatures of this age.

Next from Brihād Brahmā Rāmayan (Excerpted from Gitā Press Gorakhpur)

सर्वलोकोपकाराय प्रेरितो हरिणामुदा।

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसोस्दासस्तद् रूपेण भविष्यति।।

(Sri Brihād Brahmā Rāmāyan - 1 / 78)

Meaning: By the will of Śrī Hari, Sri Vālmiki Mahārishi will appear as Śrī Tulsidās Ji for the benefit of all people.

भाषा काव्यं मानसाख्यं रामायरणमनुत्तमम् ।

करिष्यति जनानां यत्कलौ शीघ्र फलप्रदः ॥

(Sri Brihād Brahmā Rāmāyan - 1 / 79)

Meaning- Śrī Goswami ji will make the best language poem famous by the name Śrī Mānas Rāmāyaṇa, which will give quick results to all the people in Kaliyuga.

Next from Mahākāl Samhitā,

भव रोग हरी भक्तिः शक्ति यस्व शुभ प्रदा ।
ज्ञान वैराग्य सहितं कीलकं यस्य कीर्तिम् ।
तं मानसं राम रूपं रामायणमनुत्तमम् ।
प्रणमामि सदा भक्त्या शरणं च गतोस्म्यहं ॥
श्रीमदरामायणं दिव्यं मानसं भुक्ति मुक्तिदम् ।
यस्व श्रवण मात्रेण पापिनोऽपि दिवंगताः ॥

So from all these scriptural proofs one thing is clear that Śrīmad Tulsidās Ji is not a normal poet of Kali-Yuga he is himself Śrīmad Mahārishi Vālmiki.

Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas & Hanuman Chalisa are the alone compositions which has United all Hindus in one thread. Singing it's sundarkand on every Tuesday has generated oneness among Hindus as they all sit together at one place. If Hindu's have to protest they sing Hanumān Chālisa which have been written by the author of Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas i.e. Śrīmad Tuslidās Ji Maharāj. I have personally talked to many NGO's president who are working for Hindus specially at tribal area. They all at one voice has said due to Mānas alone Hindū's are still United, if it would be not their Christian Missionaries would have converted them to Mera Yeshu Yeshu. The Raag of Mānas is such effective that it attracts all Hindū's. As it is said, “तुलसीदास ना होते तो हिंदुओं की ना चोटी होती, ना रोटी होती और ना बेटी होती"। This scripture has generated the immense power among Hindus to fight against Mughals. Leave all other, our great Hero Maharana Pratap has been motivated by Shrimad Goswami Tulsidas Ji Maharaj to fight against Mughals. Feel the intensity of Mānas what this scripture has given to India. You can't sing Vedic Hymns on road or anywhere (पहली बात तो आता ही नहीं होगा) but you can sing Mānas any time at any place. Every hindu wheather he doesn't know any Shlokā but he knows, “मंगल भवन अमंगल हारी द्रवहु सुदसरथ अजर बिहारी"

https://youtu.be/xcoSZhmjVJE

Please Chant SitaRam SitaRam SitaRam

Hail to Awadh Dulare Priya Pritam ❤️

Hail to Śrīmad Tulsidas Ji Maharaj

Hail to Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya

Comment: Do you know something...You are yourself the OP and you are giving the warnings etc. and talking rudely  to yourself only 

Comment: Ary bro actually I was pasting this answer that I posted on Quora  on quora one Guy was asking that . In all that houch Pouch I forgot that to delete  Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Yes I understood ✌️